# Bellman-Ford algorithm find path between source and destination

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Suppose we have this graph and we want to go from A to E with the least cost:

[image]

Here are my steps:

[image]

I think I am correct and I dont need any more iterations to find something new , I have found the shortest path from A to each node, the question is my destination node is E , how do I find the path(nodes) of the shortest path from A to E?

Comment: Any reaction to my post?

Answer (score 1):

Initialize a new variable called parent with `None` for each vertex in your graph. By parent I mean the predecessor to the vertex in the shortest path from the starting vertex to itself.
During the algorithm, whenever you find a shorter distance to a vertex `q` with a last edge `p -> q` update the parent of `q` to `p`.
To find the shortest path to `p`, follow its parents and grand-parents etc... till you reach the source vertex. Reverse this order to get the shortest path.

Note: We store the predecessor of a vertex in the shortest path and not a successor. This is because the shortest path to 2 or more vertices may have the same initial path. The vertex from which the the paths diverge will have to have 2 or more successor nodes in the shortest path tree. Each node, on the other hand, is guaranteed to have a single parent in the shortest path tree.